# setInterval to play sound once

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I currently have some Javascript which checks every second (using set interval) if a ticking time value is below 1 hour and if true appends the class "warning" to a html element.

I would also like to have a sound play when the time value goes below 1 hour.

I currently have the below:

```
var snd = new Audio("sound.wav");
var x = setInterval(function() {
    if (distance < 3600000 ) { 
    timer.className = "warning" ;
    playSound();
    }
    },1000);

function playSound() {
    snd.play;
    }
```

The problem I have is that once the time value goes below 1 hour (3600000 ms) it plays the sound every second as it is a part of my setinterval which checks the time each second. How do I get it to only play the once?

Comment: Use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`.

Comment: You've to restart your `distance` variable to 1hr again when it has been played once. If not, it will be always true that `distance` is less than 1hr.

Comment: use == rather than < then it will go once when the distance is exactly 3600000

Comment: clearInterval(x) can be used inside playsouund().

Comment: @andrew Bone you will be lucky if you catch right that millisecond...

Comment: @Jonasw you're right, perhaps a boolean flag would be best?

Answer (score 1):

Either stop the interval:

```
var snd = new Audio("sound.wav");
var x = setInterval(function() {
   if (distance < 3600000 ) { 
    timer.className = "warning" ;
    snd.play()
    clearInterval(x);
   }
 },1000);
```

or toggle a *warned* boolean:

```
var warned=false;
setInterval(function(){
  if(distance < 3600000 && !warned){
    timer.className="warning";
    snd.play();
    warned=true;
  }
},1000);
```

or (If distance is a regular countdown) you could use setTimeout instead:

```
setTimeout(function(){
 timer.className="warning";
 snd.play();
},Math.max(distance-3600000,0));
```

Comment: Hi Jonas,
Distance is a regular countdown so could you explain how the second "settimeout" logic works ?

Comment: @samuel phillips if youve got a 3hours countdown, you want to be warned in 2hours right? So setTimeout(warning,3hours-1hour). The math.max just keeps shure that the value is 0 or bigger, e.g. if distance is already 1/2hour it will warn in 0ms, so now